# CouchBase - string fields, starts with substring query

Tags: string, mapreduce, couchbase, string-matching

I would like to query a View for fields which start with a sub-string.

```
{
 word : "art"
},{
 word : "article"
}
```

Searching by "ar" should match both these docs.

I'm aware there is an ElasticSearch plugin, but as (currenly) this is my only string - search requirement, I wondering if there is a way to achieve this without including ElasticSearch in my architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, do a view query with a `startKey` of "ar" and an `endKey` of "ar\u02ad” (i.e. with the last Latin character at the end).

See [Partial selection and key ranges](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#partial-selection-and-key-ranges) in the Couchbase Admin guide for more details.

Comment: Thanks - I had missed that in my frantic skim reading to become a couchBase expert :)